# Manually creating laravel hash directly in SQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a site where user passwords are hashed using Laravel's Hash::make()  function.
I now have a need to manually create user's directly in the DB (MySQL). Is there a way I can create the hashed password for the user using just raw SQL?

Comment: Why are you directly putting users into the DB? Cant you just run a script to add them via laravel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, I'm afraid. Laravel uses Bcrypt, which isn't available in MySQL. In addition, it's a bad practice to do it in raw SQL, because the passwords might end up in server query logs. Sorry. :/

Answer (score 23):

You can create the password that you want via `php artisan tinker`:

1. Open the terminal on the root of your project.
2. Then write `php artisan tinker`.
3. Then `echo Hash::make('password')`;

You will see the hashed password. You can do whatever you want with that password, even with sql query directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DB Seed option in Laravel and add your users that way.
Via the DB seed you can use the hash method to hash the passwords.

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {  
        DB::table('users')->delete();
            User::create(array(
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => Hash::make('password')
            ));
    }
}
```

But if can only use raw SQL I dont have a solution for you.

For more information about DB Seed see the following page.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding

Answer (score 0):

**No!**

But you can write a function something like below

```
<?php
// Extend the base controller etc..
public function insertUsers( $passwordArray ){
    $passwordArray = array("user1" => "pass1", "user2" => "pass2");
    foreach ($passArray as $user => $pass) {
        $password = Hash::make($pass); // Laravel function
        dbQuery("INSERT INTO users (`user`, `password`) VALUES ($user, $password);
    }
}
```